# When i add numbers in a list and print them it only adds the first number

Tags: python, python-3.x, addition

When I `print(sum(n))` I get `7` instead of the sum of the elements of the list which would be `32`. What am I doing wrong?

```
def sum(numbers):
    total = 0
    for number in numbers:
        total += number
        return total

n = [7, 12, 5, 8]
print (sum(n))
```

Comment: Please take a close look at the indentation.

Comment: Also, don't define functions with the same name as built-in functions.

Comment: Try to remove your definition of the function and then `print(sum(n))`. You might be surprised.

Comment: You're returning from inside the loop. That will return from the entire function after the first iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `return` statement is in the `for` loop, then it will return the total after iterating exactly once, and so the value of `total` will be the first element in the loop: in this case, `7`. You should put the return statement after the loop so that the entire total is calculated:

```
def sum(numbers):

    total = 0

    for number in numbers:

        total += number

    return total

n = [7, 12, 5, 8]
print(sum(n))
```

However, `sum()` is already a built-in function in Python, so you could simply reduce your code to the following:

```
n = [7, 12, 5, 8]
print(sum(n))
```

Either of which will print `32`.

Comment: I'd like to see an explanation of the downvotes? To me, this is a very good answer.

Comment: the answer is ok, i will up-vote, because you answer with code an explain, so be cool. Plus one, I gert downvotes to...

Comment: @DamianLattenero Everyone who answered seems to have been down-voted within seconds of answering with no comments or alternative answer offered.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Let's explain step by step:

```
def sum(numbers):
    total = 0
    for number in numbers:
        total += number
        #If you return here, you wont sum the rest, just the first

    return total # Return must go outside the for loop, because it breaks the execution

n = [7, 12, 5, 8]
print (sum(n))
```

Comment: @zipa I hit enter by mistake... I updated, but I won't erese anything, if users want to downvote a well explained answer, and the effort of some person doesn't worth anything... not my problem

Comment: @zipa okey, sorry maybe I was a little sensitive ahahah

Comment: I sustained myself quite hard not to post answer with `reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, map(lambda x: x * 1, a))`. Just for fun :D

Answer (score 2):

Your sum is instantly returned, you don't wait for the list to loop through.

Comment: Downvoter, please be so kind and explain what is wrong. I'll gladly correct it.

Comment: You're not alone. Someone appears to have just gone through and down-voted every answer without commenting or offering a better answer of their own.

Comment: @Private_GER This answer would be better suited as a comment. I'll upvote so that you can get to 50xp but once you do, avoid posting answers like this.

Comment: I agree, I will up vote so now you can comment everywhere